# How to set time for thread to delay for some time

Tags: jmeter

Any one knows how to hold the thread for some time and again after some time run for same load 
I used Test action but still not satisfied
Can anyone help me

Thanks
S..

Answer (score 0):

Add Constant Timer in place where you want make pause.
In Constant Timer you can set thread delay